# DynamoDB TTL for active items

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

If the dynamodb TTL set to 1 min from the current time and if we perform some operation on that row(active item)...will it delete the item anyway after 1 min?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TTL is an attribute with timestamp. Only when your update extends the timestamp, you can change TTL expiration. Updating other attributes of an item does not affect TTL.

But anyway, TTL can take up to 48 hours to delete your item, so do not rely on a period of 1 min. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/howitworks-ttl.html):

> TTL typically deletes expired items within **48 hours** of expiration.

Comment: seem like the OP should consider elasticache or some other caching with a TTL of only 1min rather than trying to use DDB as a cache.